# IronPython in Visual Studio code

Tags: python, ironpython, visual-studio-code, revit

I want to use visual studio code instead of Revit-Dynamo python node. So, I added IronPython stubs and did the steps over this wiki (https://github.com/gtalarico/ironpython-stubs). but I still get some errors. since it is irritating, is there a way to avoid these problems?[Problems in VSCode with IronPython](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0AoS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off such warnings in Pylint either by using a custom `.pylintrc` file, specifying the appropriate flags on the command-line through your `settings.json`, or turn linting off entirely with `"python.linting.enabled": false`.

As for those stubs, you can add them in [`"python.autoComplete.extraPaths"`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_autocomplete-and-intellisense), but that won't affect Pylint, only IntelliSense.

Comment: Thank you. I just added another statement: "python.linting.enabled": false,